# What is $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k n!}{k!(k+n)!}$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

What is $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k n!}{k!(k+n)!}$?

If we abuse the notation a little bit, it is  $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom n {-k}(-x)^k$. What is its value and how to tackle it algebraically?

It is also of probabilistic meanings, in fact the question itself comes from computing $\mathbb P(X_1-X_2=k)$ where $X_1, X_2$ are Poisson distributions with parameters $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$. I wanted to prove by directly computing that $X_1 - X_2$ is a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda_1 - \lambda_2$.

Comment: Probabilistic proofs are also welcomed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Look up the modified Bessel function $I_n$.

Comment: More generally, (infinite) sums that have rational coefficients in the summation variable are hypergeometric functions.

Comment: $\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{n!}{(k + n)!} \cdot \frac{x^k}{k!} \right] = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{1}{(1 + n)_k} \cdot \frac{x^{k}}{k!} \right] = \operatorname{_{0}F_{1}}\left( \cdot;\, 1 + n;\, x \right)$ where $_0F_1$ is a [hypergeometric function](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric0F1/02/) and $(a)_{b}$ is *the* [pochhammer symbol](https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Pochhammer/02/). You could write this in terms of [Bessel functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric0F1/27/ShowAll.html).

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution